# Integrals of power-logarithm combonations

Tags: logarithms, indefinite-integrals

Are there any approximations, or expansions to evaluate integrals of the form: $$\int \frac{(x-K)^{-a}}{\log(x)} dt, \quad a \geq 2.$$ Even for a special case of K $\in \mathbb{N}^+$ for example $K = 1, a = 2$, does there exist a closed form expression or even a method to proceed towards an approximation.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5B(x-1)%5E(-2)%2Flog(x),x%5D

Comment: Perhaps look up the logarithmic integral.

Comment: @SimpleArt, I did not get what you meant. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @tired Wolfram Alpha is not giving closed form results. I was wondering if this integral can be approximated by any function.

Comment: is one of the parameters big or small?

Comment: If you take the binomial expansion, I think you can write a series expansion with logarithmic integrals.

Comment: @tired Well, parameters can be assumed to be constant, for example: a = 2, and K = 1

Comment: @SimpleArt, OK, I see what you mean. Let me give it a try.

Comment: @SimpleArt, I realized that in my case it is not true that $|x| \leq 1$, so Binomial Theorem may not be applied to expand.

Comment: Yes, but you can adjust the binomial expansion so it converges for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Integration and exponents. Integral of f(x)^2* (dx)^2. VS. Integral of F(x)dx.  BTA.